# Laravel 5.3 ModelFactory Seeder Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Im trying to create a seeder table that fills a table with some dummy data using the laravel ModelFactory. I keep getting this error and I'm out of ideas on fixing it.

The 'Race' Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Game;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Race extends Model
{
//
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['name','description','icon'];
}
```

File 2 The Model Factory File

```
$factory->define(App\Game\Race::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'description' => $faker->text,
        'icon' => $faker->url,
    ];
});
```

File 3 The Seeder File

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RacesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
        factory(App\Game\Race::class, 10)->create()->each(function($u) {
           $u->posts()->save(factory(App\Game\Race::class)->make());
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

This happens when I call 'php artisan db:seed'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you copied the seeder directly from [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding#using-model-factories).  In the documentation's example, there is a `User` model that is related to a `Posts` model via a function `posts` that is defined within the user model. See [this documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) for more information about why there's a `posts` method on the `User` model.

You have a `Race` model that does not have `Posts` related to it, indicated by the absence of `posts` method inside your race model.  Try simplifying the factory to this:

```
public function run()
{
    //
    factory(App\Game\Race::class, 10)->create();
}
```

This should create 10 race entries in your database for you.  You would want to provide the closure passed to the `each` method only if you intend to also create other models within the seeder that are related to each instance the factory creates, or do some other action *for every instance* (`each`) of a `Race` that gets created by the factory.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is my first time using laravel.  This worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. And welcome to the light.

Comment: Thanks is correct your answer...  in the case of user Model would be:  factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();